# Python Can I add a tuple to a generator?

Tags: python, django, forms, tuples, generator

I want to add ('', 'Day') to the front. Right now it makes a drop down menu for the numbers 1 through 31 and I want a 'Day' choice at the top.

```
DAY_CHOICES = (
    # I was hoping this would work but apparently generators don't work like this.
    # ('', 'Day'),
    (str(x), x) for x in range(1,32)
)

# I'll include this in the snippet in case there's some voodoo I can do here
from django import forms
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    day = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DAY_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bad use of generators. A generator is not a list, it is a function that generates a sequence of values, so it is not possible to "add a tuple to a generator".

The generator will be exhausted after the model initialization. You might for instance want to use DAY_CHOICES again later -- which will not be possible.

If you do not have any very specific reason for using a generator here, I would recommend turning DAY_CHOICES to a list instead:

```
DAY_CHOICES = [('', 'Day')] + [(str(x), x) for x in range(1,32)]
```

Comment: Seems more appropriate to use this instead.

Comment: In a general case, sure. But in this specific case you will never reuse the generator.

Comment: You are right. But it is better to make it a tuple, since its value probably won't change: ``DAY_CHOICES = (('', 'Day'),) + tuple((str(x), x) for x in range(1,32))`` or ``DAY_CHOICES = tuple( (str(x),x) if x>0 else('','Day') for x in range(0,32) )``

Comment: I changed it to a tuple as per your suggestion eyquem.

Answer (score 6):

You want [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
for i in itertools.chain(('foo', 'bar'), xrange(1, 4)):
  print i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DAY_CHOICES = ( (str(x),x) if x>0 else('','Day') for x in range(0,32) )
```

Comment: The objective is not to print it but instead to pass it as an argument to a constructor.

Comment: If the developer has absolute control of the original iterable, yes.